# Can I add data to SQLite server continuously in real time and read from it at the same time using python

Tags: python, sqlite, matplotlib

I am reading voltages from a device continuously which I want to log data on to an SQLite database in real-time. Is it possible to add and read the data from the database so that I can plot it? I am using matplotlib in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason why you couldn't. If the database is locked by a write, the read(s) will block for that time.

You might want to try the [SQLite WAL mode](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) for better concurrent performance by running

```
PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;
```

as the first command of your SQLite connection.

Comment: Thanks for the advice ill go through it.